# How i can fix my if else selenium Python?

Tags: python, if-statement, helper

```
def refreshing(self):
        if "In den Warenkorb" in self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("cart-btn-text").text:
            print("Gefunden")
            time.sleep(100)
            self.verfuegbar()
        else:
            print("nope")
            self.driver.refresh()
            time.sleep(5)
            self.refreshing()
```

does anyone know how it can work??
why do I get an error at if "In den Warenkorb" in self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("cart-btn-text").text:
it doesn't do my else

Error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alala\Desktop\Crappy\Crappy.py", line 54, in <module>
    checkout_bot = CheckOutBot()
  File "C:\Users\Alala\Desktop\Crappy\Crappy.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.accept_cookies()
  File "C:\Users\Alala\Desktop\Crappy\Crappy.py", line 20, in accept_cookies
    self.open()
  File "C:\Users\Alala\Desktop\Crappy\Crappy.py", line 27, in open
    self.refreshing()
  File "C:\Users\Alala\Desktop\Crappy\Crappy.py", line 30, in refreshing
    if "In den Warenkorb" in self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("cart-btn-text").text:
  File "D:\Users\Alala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 564, in find_element_by_class_name
    return self.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value=name)
  File "D:\Users\Alala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "D:\Users\Alala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "D:\Users\Alala\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".cart-btn-text"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.72)
```

Comment: please update your question with the error trace

Comment: it would help us answer your question if you provide the error message you are seeing.  including stack information if that is present.

Comment: if you are getting nulltype does not have attribute text the issue is the find by class call did not return any results.

Comment: `find element by class` cannot find element, therefore it gives error and code doesn't reach your `else` statement. You need to catch this situation with probably `try... except` construction

Comment: Thanks for help with try and except work it fine